# POI protectsheet

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am trying to edit existing sheet,add new values to it and protect newly created workbook.
From searching on net I came to know that sheet.protectSheet("some_password") is helpful.
But in my case the compiler gives error that protectSheet method is not there.
Then I tried using sheet.setProtect(true), but on execution it gives following error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet.setProtect(HSSFSheet.java:890)
```

Here is my code:

```
FileInputStream fsIP= new FileInputStream(new File(request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath(".")+ "/Cheque Printing.xls"));

HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fsIP);

HSSFSheet worksheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
```

Is the problem that I am accessing sheet via getSheetAt and not via createSheet ?

Comment: Please take a look another answer on SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14701322/apache-poi-how-to-protect-sheet-with-options

Comment: i want to use hssf not xssf can it help me this way?

Comment: I am not sure which version of Apache POI you are using. But the latest version has a simple and straightforward method. https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFSheet.html#protectSheet(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 0):

Without updating my poi library I found this solution:

Make your reference excel sheet protected and change above line to:

`HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fsIP,true);`

Thats it! Rest of the code is same.