# Enable drop down in xls once sheet is protected

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I need to enable the drop-down (filters) in a protected XLS sheet. I have written below code and also attached the XLS which gets generated from it. When you open the excel you will see the drop down filters however it will not be enabled for selection.

Constraints I have are:
I need to keep the protection of the sheet on and I need this feature in XLS format file only (not XLSX).

Thanks for your help,

Shashank

```
String excelFileName = "C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\GN_Files\\Test.xls";//name of excel file
        String sheetName = "Sheet1";//name of sheet
        HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();

        HSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet(sheetName) ;
        //sheet.protectSheet("");
        //iterating r number of rows
        CellStyle style=wb.createCellStyle();
        style.setLocked(false);
        sheet.setAutoFilter(CellRangeAddress.valueOf("A1:C3"));
        for (int r=0;r < 3; r++ )
        {
              HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(r);

              //iterating c number of columns

              for (int c=0;c < 3; c++ )
              {
                    if(r==1){
                    HSSFCell cell = row.createCell(c);
                    cell.setCellValue(1);
                    //cell.setCellStyle(style);
                    }
                    if(r==2){
                          HSSFCell cell = row.createCell(c);
                          cell.setCellValue(2);
                          //cell.setCellStyle(style);
                          }
                    if(r==0){
                          HSSFCell cell = row.createCell(c);
                          cell.setCellValue(0);
                          cell.setCellStyle(style);
                          }
              }

        }

        sheet.protectSheet("");
        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(excelFileName);
        //write this workbook to an Outputstream.
        wb.write(fileOut);
        fileOut.flush();
        fileOut.close();
        wb.close();
        System.out.println("done-----");
```

Comment: **What** below code?

Comment: That isn't [tag:vba]. Looks to be [tag:poi].

Comment: Just shared, please review.

Comment: You decided to comment out your worksheet protect code but your answer seems to be in one of the responses to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14701322/apache-poi-how-to-protect-sheet-with-options).

Comment: @Jeeped: I have already referred to the answer you have pointed however I need to perform locking and enabling the Filters (which can be selected) on XLS format. On the XLSX files I am able to achieve it easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [OpenOffice BIFF8 documentation](https://www.openoffice.org/sc/excelfileformat.pdf#page=208&zoom=auto,85.6,771.1) is the SHEETPROTECTION a BIFF record in the `Sheet Substream`. So we need inserting that record there.

Unfortunatelly does `apache poi` not supporting this. So we can only doing this ourselfs. I following example I get the [InternalSheet](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/model/InternalSheet.html#getRecords--) and the records in it using reflection. Then I provide a new class `SheetProtectionRecord` which is created according to OpenOffice BIFF8 documentation. The bytes 19 and 20 of the `byte[] data` are the ones which are the `Option flags`.

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.*;

import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.record.RecordBase;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.record.StandardRecord;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.model.InternalSheet;
import org.apache.poi.util.LittleEndianOutput;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;

import java.util.List;

public class CreateExcelHSSFProtectedSheet {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
  HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();

  sheet.setAutoFilter(CellRangeAddress.valueOf("A1:C3"));
  HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(0);
  for (int c = 0; c < 3; c++) {
   row.createCell(c).setCellValue("Col " + (c+1));
  }

  for (int r = 1; r < 4; r++) {
   row = sheet.createRow(r);
   for (int c = 0; c < 3; c++) {
    row.createCell(c).setCellValue(r * (c+1)); 
   }
  }

  sheet.protectSheet("");
  Field _sheet = HSSFSheet.class.getDeclaredField("_sheet");
  _sheet.setAccessible(true); 
  InternalSheet internalsheet = (InternalSheet)_sheet.get(sheet); 

  Field _records = InternalSheet.class.getDeclaredField("_records");
  _records.setAccessible(true);
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") 
  List<RecordBase> records = (List<RecordBase>)_records.get(internalsheet);

  SheetProtectionRecord sheetprotection = new SheetProtectionRecord();
  sheetprotection.lockAutoFilter(false);
  sheetprotection.lockInsertRows(false);
  sheetprotection.lockInsertHyperlinks(false);

  records.add(records.size() - 1, sheetprotection); 

/*  
  for (RecordBase r : internalsheet.getRecords()) {
   System.out.println(r);
  }
*/

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("CreateExcelHSSFProtectedSheet.xls");
  workbook.write(out);
  out.close();
  workbook.close();

 }

 static class SheetProtectionRecord extends StandardRecord {

  //see https://www.openoffice.org/sc/excelfileformat.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A635%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C85.6%2C771.1%2C0%5D

  byte[] data = new byte[]{(byte)0x67, 0x08, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0x00, 0x01,  (byte)0xFF, (byte)0xFF, (byte)0xFF, (byte)0xFF, 0x00, (byte)0x44, 0x00, 0x00};

  public int getDataSize() { 
   return 23; 
  }

  public short getSid() {
   return (short)0x0867;
  }

  void lockAutoFilter(boolean lock) {
   if(lock) data[20] &= 0xEF;
   else data[20] |= 0x10;
  } 

  void lockSelectLockedCells(boolean lock) {
   if(lock) data[20] &= 0xFB;
   else data[20] |= 0x04;
  }

  void lockSelectUnLockedCells(boolean lock) {
   if(lock) data[20] &= 0xBF;
   else data[20] |= 0x40;
  }

  void lockInsertRows(boolean lock) {
   if(lock) data[19] &= 0xBF;
   else data[19] |= 0x40;
  }

  void lockInsertHyperlinks(boolean lock) {
   if(lock) data[19] &= 0x7F;
   else data[19] |= 0x80;
  }
  //further methods ....

  public void serialize(LittleEndianOutput out) {
   out.write(data);
  }
 }

}
```

---

Using current `apache poi 5.0.0` there are multiple abstract methods which needs override in class `SheetProtectionRecord`.

```
...
import org.apache.poi.hssf.record.HSSFRecordTypes;
...
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.function.Supplier;

 static class SheetProtectionRecord extends StandardRecord {
 ...

  @Override
  public SheetProtectionRecord copy() {
   return null; // not supported
  }

  @Override
  public HSSFRecordTypes getGenericRecordType() {
   return null; // not supported
  }
 
  @Override
  public Map<String, Supplier<?>> getGenericProperties() {
   return null; // not supported
  }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Axel. This solves my question. Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: @Shashank Pandey: Glad if I helped you. Please read [Help Center > Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) -> [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Just a small query, is there any other way to lock few cells and make every other cell/row open for edit. I am aware that we need to protect the sheet first and then create a style which has setLocked(false). Now whichever cell we need to make editable we set this as style.

Comment: @Shashank Pandey: No there is no other way than using a style, which has setLocked(false), for each cell which shall not be locked.